# Pandas linear regression: use normalisation (StandardScaler) only on non-categorical values

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataset which I'm reading into a Pandas dataframe:

```
age gender  bmi     smoker  married region  value
39  female  23.0    yes     no      us      136
28  male    22.0    no      no      us      143
23  male    34.0    no      yes     europe  153
17  male    29.0    no      no      asia    162
```

Gender, smoker and region are categorical values. So I convert them (using replace function for gender and smoker and one hot encoding for region. The result is the following:

```
age sex bmi     smoker  married value r_asia r_europe r_us
39  1   23.0    1       0       136   0      0        1
28  0   22.0    0       0       143   0      0        1
23  0   34.0    0       1       153   0      1        0
17  0   29.0    0       0       162   1      0        0
```

Then I'm splitting into features and target

```
y = dataset['value'].values
X = dataset.drop('value',axis=1).values
```

Next I'm splitting into a training and test set:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
```

As a next step I want to normalise. Normally I would do:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
```

However this also normalises the categorical values. I want to only normalise the non-categorical value (in this example the only non-categorical value is 'bmi').

How can I only normalise the 'bmi' column and insert these normalised values into X_train and X_test?

Comment: Simply use the column names saved as categorical. `X_train[numerical_cols] = scaler.transform(X_train[numerical_cols])`

Comment: I tried using `X_train['bmi'] = scaler.transform(X_train['bmi'])` but then I get the following error message `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Answer (score 0):

[train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) returns a list of NumPy arrays (X_train is one of them), not dataframes, so `X_train["bmi"]` raises an exception. Same for [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
print(X_train)
# Output <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[28 'male' 22.0 'no' 'no' 'us']
 [39 'female' 23.0 'yes' 'no' 'us']]
```

So, here is one way to do it:

```py
# Back to Pandas
X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train)

# Fit and transform the target column (2 == "bmi")
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train.loc[:, 2].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
X_train[2] = scaler.transform(X_train.loc[:, 2].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))

# Revert to Numpy
X_train = X_train.to_numpy()
```

```py
print(X_train)
# Output
[[28 'male' -1.0 'no' 'no' 'us']
 [39 'female' 1.0 'yes' 'no' 'us']]
```